# SQL Server 2008 R2 import from access fails on datetime column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to import an Access 2010 DB table (`*.accdb`) to SQL Server 2008 R2,
as a new table not to an existing one.

I'm doing it through SQL Server's "Import an Export Data Wizard".

I have two `datetime` columns that I know for a fact that contain some non valid `datetime` values (don't ask me how some genius managed to enter bad values there).

So I thought I can map these columns to `nvarchar(max)` columns in the wizard and deal with the problem later.

But unfortunately after the mapping, I get this message:

> Found 2 unknown column type conversion(s)
>   The package will not be run.

This is a screenshot:

[image: import_error.png]

Comment: For information - The recommended way to share images with us via http://imgur.com/

Comment: Fields of data type DateTime cannot hold invalid entries. If you think that is the case, do a repair and compact on the Access database.

Comment: @Gustav - tried what you suggested - not working. i know that it holds invalid data because if i keep the destination type "datetime" it fails in the middle of the import proccess with an error regarding this column

Comment: Again, an Access date field _cannot_ hold invalid date values. However, the date range in SQL Server is limited compared to that of Access (100/01/01 to 9999/12/31), so study your table for excessive values.

Comment: @Gustav - are Null Values considered to be legit values for the wizard?

Comment: It should be, but it would be easy to locate such values.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so i just found a very weird workaround (bug in the wizard?):
when you choose the destination column type to be "nvarchar" the size is set automatically to "max" and you **can't** change that.

switched to "nchar" (next on the combobox list) and the size is set to "50" (deafult).
then switched back to "nvarchar" and the size was still "50", pressed "next" button and voila - i can choose to ignore bad values and was able to run the import.
weirdest workaround ever.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the workaround described in another answer, another approach would be to import a query that does the DateTime -> Text conversion, for example,

```sql
SELECT CStr(Field1) AS Field1Text, Field2 FROM Table1
```

like this:

[image: Import1.png]

[image: Import2.png]

Comment: thanks for the answer. tried your suggestion. got this error: http://tinyurl.com/onkc46w

Comment: Unfortunately that error message does not provide much (any) useful information. Perhaps the bad dates are causing the query to fail. It would be interesting to know if the query also fails when run from within Access itself.

Comment: it doesn't fail pre say - it returns "#error" for a lot of the rows, for the others it returns the date value as string.
edit: found out that some of the returned #error are because of Null values...